# Salt Water Metal etching 50 (Euro-)Cent Coin

Tags: metal, electrolysis

I want to etch the 50 Cent Euro Coin using this following technique that I came across on some DIY site: Immerse the coin and some disposable piece of metal in salt water such that they do not touch and attach current. Cover the non-to-be-etched parts of the coin with nail polish.

The article proposed to use a 9V battery block and used brass in their example. I understand the 50 Cent coin is made out of [Nordic Gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordic_Gold): Is this etching method still viable, and does the 9V block deliver enough energy to at least remove the imprinting of the coin? Is there something else to consider (safety isseus)?

Unfortunately, I have no noteworthy background in chemistry. Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Comment: What stops you from trying it? Chemistry is an experimental science, they say.

Comment: I certainly will try.  Unfortunately, my situation (abroad + time pressure) does not allow for extensive experimenting. Are there some obvious Do's and Don'ts or comments on my endeavour?

Comment: Don't get electrocuted. That's it

Comment: Thank you. What about the energy needed? Will the 9V block (600mAh) suffice or would I be better off with e.g. a 12V 7000mAH motorcycle battery? How many amps do I need to make reasonable progress?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because from the nature/tone of your question, it sounds awfully like you have absolutely no idea about the chemistry/electronics of what you're considering doing and are likely to cause harm to yourself/others. The question is also not specifically asking about the chemistry involved.

Comment: That is ok. While I wouldn't mind an explanation of the chemistry involved, a suitable (for me) explanation will perhaps be of no benefit to the community. If yes, please close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ECM ([electrochemical machining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrochemical_machining)) is a safe (besides risk of getting electrocuted: **keep your hands dry**) way to carve metal. However, *only electrically conductive materials can be machined.* Both aluminum and copper are conductive, therefore you can carve it safely.

Comment: Thanks, it works just fine. I‘ve noticed some gases/steam(/smoke?) developing in the process, what is this? Heated water?